# Difference between missile and bombs in Wings of Prey

Tags: wings-of-prey

During tutorial it was stated that missile 'are heavy and their flight is anything but straight line' and 'require direct hit'. However I found he missiles much more precise then bombs.

I assume that I have misunderstood the statement about missiles - but then when should I use bombs?

Comment: Please add 'wings-of-pray' tag as I have insufficient privileges to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bombs operate in an large area of effect way while missles fly towards where you are targeting with a smaller aoe attack though a bit of guess work or spamming is required if you want to hit something far. IMO i prefer the rockets over the bombs since its faster to kill enemies.